# setting function path in php?

Tags: php, path, include, include-path

I have gcm in folder (dirC)...here the paths

```
index.php
dirA/    
dirB/    
dirC/GCM.php    
----/config.php
----/sendMsg.php
dirD/
dirE/dirE1/test.php            //send from here
dirF/
```

gcm.php have code bellow

```
class GCM {

    function __construct() {

    }

    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';
          //other code here
        echo 'test';

     }
}
```

and i successfull send message from sendMsg.php,here the code

```
include_once './GCM.php';
    $message="hello word";
    $gcm = new GCM();
    $registatoin_ids = array("SEJFOJOEUJFPUWPJR0923740JEU092308UPUPUAUOJLJLJJVPW634");
    $message = array($message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
    echo $result;
```

my question is how to **set the path** to communicate with GCM.php using include_once from `test.php` ?

here test.php code

```
include_once './GCM.php'; //my proble is here ???????????
$message="hello word";
$gcm = new GCM();
$registatoin_ids = array("SEJFOJOEUJFPUWPJR0923740JEU092308UPUPUAUOJLJLJJVPW634");
$message = array($message);

$result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
echo $result;
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: if GCM.php is in another directory you can browse to that directory with ../ (1 directory up).

Comment: what diference using 2point (../) and (./) ?

Comment: ../ is move one directory up ./ is current directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to get to your desired directory, you need to use ../, which means 'move one directory up'.

Example:
we have a directory structure:

```
/website
/website/include
/website/template
```

Imagine we are in /website/template directory.
If we want to include /website/include/GCM.php

We can do it with an absolute path, / means the root directory:

```
include_once '/website/include/GCM.php';
```

We can do it with a relative path:

```
include_once '../include/GCM.php';
```

../ means 'move 1 directory up'.

For more information: http://www.geeksengine.com/article/absolute-relative-path.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear. But i think the problem is that you make a folder, from which you include and you dont know what folder that is?

For that you have magic constants in php:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

From php documentation you can do something like that :

```
$path = '/dirC';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

In your index.php (if it's your controller), or in a conf/prepend file, which is included in all your script.

Then a simple `include('GCM.php');` will work.